# Using complex route Razor Page routing conventions that involve multiple variables in paths

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

### Background

.NetCore 2 web application targetting the full .Net framework. We are moving from the conventional MVC separate Controller/View structure where we configured route rules using [Route()]/Get() attributes to handle routing to Razor Pages.

### So far

Following the MS docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-convention-features#page-model-action-conventions) I have the first tier of folders with a category ID being passed to the page;

e.g. '/category/15032/dashboard/' resolves to the page '*pages*/category/dashboard'

```
`options.Conventions
        .AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/category", model =>
        {
            int selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                SelectorModel selector = model.Selectors[i];
                string[] segments = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Split('/');
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = 1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates($"category/{{categoryid}}/{segments[1].ToLower()}", "{categoryPageTemplate?}")
                    }
                });
            }
        });`
```

This works as expected. However, the problems arise when I try to add further depth to the folder structure.

### The problem

Each category contains a sub-category, and then within that, an item. For example, I will include a deeply nested page.

e.g. '/category/15032/subcategory/543/item/211/status' should resolve to the page '*pages*/category/subcategory/item/status'

The hope was that adding the following convention would handle this;

```
`options.Conventions
        .AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/category/subcategory/item", model =>
        {
            int selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                SelectorModel selector = model.Selectors[i];
                string[] segments = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Split('/');
                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = 1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates($"category/{{categoryid}}/subcategory/{{subcategoryid}}/item/{{itemid}}/{segments[2].ToLower()}",
                                                                        "{itemPageTemplate?}")
                    }
                });
            }
        });`
```

#### Error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: The following
>   errors occurred with attribute routing information:
>
> For action: 'Page: /category/subcategory/item/dashboard' Error: The
>   route parameter name 'categoryid' appears more than one time in the
>   route template. Parameter name: routeTemplate
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.GetRouteInfos(IReadOnlyList
>   1 actions)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.AddEntries(TreeRouteBuilder
>   builder, ActionDescriptorCollection actions)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.GetTreeRouter()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AttributeRoute.RouteAsync(RouteContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

### Question

Note: the folders are nested like this because there are quite a few pages to the site, so keeping things organised is quite important.

How can I avoid this error? Do I have to change the URL structure - this has proven fairly readable (don't normally use ID numbers)? Does anyone have any examples of a similar nested structure (I have had difficulty in finding examples)?